# I watched a movie with porn

Tags: sex, halal-haram

I watched a movie that had porn. I did not see them having it but I heard it. Is it ok to hear moaning or porn noises

Answer (score 1):

Pornography is Haram in Islam and you must guard your eyes from from those things which Allah has forbidden. You said you didn't watch them but hear them. But there is a huge possibility that temptation will force you watch those which Allah has forbidden. I recommend you not to watch these type of movie because if they contain nudity it is Haram. Brother please stay away from these and watch movies that have no Haram content because your Nafs(desire) might force you to sin and there will be satanic whispers.
Jazakallah Khairan